# If item in list contains a keyword remove it

Tags: python

I have a list of items

```
['InvalidAddressBecauseDestinationIsAlsoSource', 
'NotEnoughBalanceBecauseDestinationNotCreated', 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 
'ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL', 
'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 
'BPFLoader1111111111111111111111111111111111',  
'gatbGF9DvLAw3kWyn1EmH5Nh1Sqp8sTukF7yaQpSc71', 
'ni1jXzPTq1yTqo67tUmVgnp22b1qGAAZCtPmHtskqYG', 
'mos1x4hXqmmmWz5s8btUsM1aHxdY3tUvNHf7sfK37Y6', 
'yukonJRbdjiiSMqXmMq3mVHsVTLg7FSzEpVwZU3fzzr', 
'tgaxdij8CgAbfDDkhtkvZgEtwLPrVEXTQe3L4zkA7gE', 
'tniC2HX5yg2yDjMQEcUo1bHa44x9YdZVSqyKox21SDz', 
'tmo7YXBjHgJ74StE7inz5XkyJQ5dq9CEy5YERZfx6iZ', 
'tyukPUmtWLzTx7YqJus93gBQ1u3tYispTJDXnQXp7Hp', 
'gatem74V238djXdzWnJf94Wo1DcnuGkfijbf3AuBhfs', 
'ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL', 
'gatem74V238djXdzWnJf94Wo1DcnuGkfijbf3AuBhfs', 
'cndy3Z4yapfJBmL3ShUp5exZKqR3z33thTzeNMm2gRZ', 
'metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s', 
'EfLbqXBzgbXURKsjE5UTbf9khGW9Ck9UvzFr5Uyh53pw']
```

and I have a list of keywords

`LIST2 = ['meta', 'cndy', '11111111', 'Token', 'gate', 'Invalid', 'NotEnough']`

and I want to remove items from the first list if they match any item in the second list

I tried

```py
LIST2 = ['meta', 'cndy', '11111111', 'Token', 'gate', 'Invalid', 'NotEnough']
finalResult = newlist = [m for m in LIST1if not any(k for k in LIST2 if k in ' '.join(m))]
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your membership testing wrong, you want:

```
finalResult = [m for m in LIST1 if not any(k in m for k in LIST2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this part:

```
' '.join(m)
```

Because for example this string:

```
'InvalidAddressBecauseDestinationIsAlsoSource'
```

becomes

```
'I n v a l i d A d d r e s s B e c a u s e D e s t i n a t i o n I s A l s o S o u r c e'
```

and obviously `'Invalid'` cannot be found within `'I n v a l i d'`.

So replace that part:

```
' '.join(m)
```

with simply:

```
m
```

thus having:

```
newlist = [m for m in LIST1 if not any(k for k in LIST2 if k in m)]
```

and it will work.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you.